# When executing c# swagger api string parameter is not passing as null

Tags: c#, api, swagger

When I passing parameters into my httpGet api method I have a string parameter and when the api is executed eventhough no parameter was entered it returns { bookType }

BookId is required that is fine but when I don't pass anything into bookType in the code it comes through as { bookType } so in code it isn't null because it equals { bookType }

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("getBooks")]
public int getBooks(string bookid, string bookType = null)
{ code here }
```

It is being executed like

```
Http://localhost/api/books/getBooks?bookId=123&bookType={ bookType }
```

But why is it.literally passing into the parameter { bookType } It would expect it to pass in a type if entered or it not entered then  null

Comment: Please post the code of how you call this method and pass the parameters.

Comment: Its a httpGet controller method I am calling it from a Swagger UI using routing

Comment: What parameter values do you enter in Swagger UI? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Do you use Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net or something else? Are the controller, methods and parameters annotated properly?

Comment: I believe so yeah. Parameter type is path and data type is string

Comment: Curl - X --header ' Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost/api/books/getBooks?bookId=123&bookType={bookType} '

Comment: Well, this cURL command explicitly passes the value `{bookType}` for this parameter. Have you tried passing an empty value?